# Node: Can't bind to IPv6 localAddress while using https.request()

Tags: node.js

I can bind to **`localAddress`** just fine when using HTTP, but as soon as I switch to HTTPS I get an  error: **`bind EINVAL`**. Please consider this code:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var options = { host:'icanhazip.com',path:'/',localAddress:'2604:a880:1:20::27:a00f',family:6 };
callback = function(response) {
  var data = '';
  response.on('data',function(chunk) { data+= chunk; });
  response.on('error',function(error) { console.log("error: "+error.message); });
  response.on('end',function() {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
http.request(options,callback).end(); // Works. IP:2604:a880:1:20::27:a00f
https.request(options,callback).end(); // Fails. IP:2604:a880:1:20::27:a00f
https.request({host:'icanhazip.com',path:'/',family:6},callback).end(); // Works. IP:2604:a880:1:20::27:a00f
```

Here's the error while running node v5.0.0:

```
Error: bind EINVAL 2604:a880:1:20::27:a00f
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:860:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:883:20)
    at connect (net.js:809:16)
    at net.js:984:7
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:63:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:82:10)
```

The only difference between the working and the failing code is setting **`localAddress`** and ironically, the last example binds to the correct IP address, but won't let you do it using **`localAddress`**.

The problem here is I have to make a request from a completely separate IPv6 address under my use case, and it works fine with HTTP but I need this to work for HTTPS requests. Currently I can only make this work while using cURL. Could you please provide some insight as to why this is happening or how I could make this work without additional libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue as you. Figured it out.  Update your node to the latest stable.  They fixed it. Check it with `node --version` I'm on `6.6.0` and it works great.

The version I got from doing an apt-get was way too old.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I filed a bug report here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4139

Comment: I just updated and can also confirm it's working. Thanks!